# Что конкретно делает выражение mappedBy в аннотации @ManyToMany?

Tags: java, hibernate

Начал изучение Hibernate и пока не могу понять что конкретно делает выражение mappedBy. В оффициальной документации написано:

```
The field that owns the relationship. Required unless
the relationship is unidirectional. 

Поле, которому принадлежат отношения. Требуется, если связь не является однонаправленной.
```

Но суть так и не могу понять. Вот вырезка из кода:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    private Set<Book> books  = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: mapped by говорит о том, в какой таблице находится первичный ключ.

Comment: это ссылка на внешний ключ, который хранится у собственника ассоциации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итого. Напишу ответ, какой бы я хотел получить, на момент написания этого вопроса.
У нас есть две таблицы: BorderShip и СrewMember. Они связаны между собой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В официальной документации написано про mapped by:

```
Поле, которому принадлежат отношения. Требуется, если связь не является однонаправленной.
```

То есть в mapped by в главном классе указывается имя переменной (поле) дочернего класса по которому происходит соединение таблиц.

Также рекомендую прочитать вот эту [статью](https://function-x.ru/sql_join.html) для большего понимания понятия соединения таблиц:

Comment: спасибо! Странно, что ответов не было

Comment: Получается, это нужно для JOIN'ов только?